# how to shrink the size of the image that has opened in jupyter notebook by using " ![description](image source) " markdown comand

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have tried to open image files in my jupyter notebook using
`![description](image_source)` markdown code.

But the problem with the above approach is that the image I tried to open is too big and the other problem is, if the image that I am trying to open is of high resolution then that image is not opening at all.

Please tell me if there are any attributes for this markdown code to shrink the image size.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the markdown in Jupyter notebooks can handle several HTML tags directly, you can use the third option shown [here](https://gist.github.com/uupaa/f77d2bcf4dc7a294d109#try-resize-it) to display images in Jupyter notebooks. It is more succinctly spelled out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047529/8508004).

```
<img src="path/to/image1" width="45%"/>
<img src="path/to/image2" width="200"/>
```

Alternatively you can use use the `style` CSS property within the `<img>` tag like illustrated [here](https://owlcation.com/stem/how-to-align-images-side-by-side) under the section 'HTML / CSS Codes to Tile Images' and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_images.asp) under 'Responsive Images' to control the dimensions in the markdown.